# Assign steps/instructions to loop python

Tags: python

I have a text file in which i list instructions (e.g. go to website, click on link). What i want to do is complete each action in `[data]` according to the steps in `[steps]`. Now, i already have a mechanism to extract the files, but am not able to do each action based on each step.

File parsing:

```
file_name = "testdata.txt"
with open(file_name) as f:
      pre_data,post_data =[s.strip() for s in (f.read()).split("[data]")]
post_data_lines = post_data.splitlines()
headers = post_data_lines[0].split()
headers2 = [s.replace("_"," ").strip() for s in headers]
for line in post_data_lines[1:]:
    tmpline  = []
    pos = 0
    for itm in headers:
        tmpline.append(line[pos:pos+len(itm)])
        pos += len(itm)+1

    print dict(zip(headers2,tmpline))
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
[Steps]
step1 = WebAddress
step2 = Tab
step3 = SecurityType
step4 = Criteria
step5 = Date
Step6 = Click1
step7 = Results
step8 = Download
[data]
WebAddress___________________________ Destination___________ Tab_____________ SecurityType___________________________________________________ Criteria___ Date_______ Click1_ Results_ Download    
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Interim MBS: Single-Family                                      Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Preliminary Mega: Fannie Mae/Ginnie Mae backed Adjustable Rate  Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Preliminary Mega: Fannie Mae/Ginnie Mae backed Fixed Rate       Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
```

Comment: Are you trying to script web access, and the various "steps" correspond to web-related actions?  Are you familiar with tools like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)?

Comment: I am currently using selenium, but i am having trouble reading the file and then processing so that each step is a click, or a url, etc.

Comment: I am just not sure how to parse the file correctly and then use the date in my script, my webcrawler works, but I just need to get the parsing and using the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

all pseudocode below...

is this what you're trying to do ?

```
class StairMaster(object):
    def step1(self,data):
        pass
    def step2(self,data):
        pass

for line in testdata_dicts:
    dispatcher = StairMaster()
    for i in range(1,8):
        step = "step%s" % i
        data = line[step]
        result = getattr( dispatcher , step )( data )
```

or is this what you're trying to do:

```
instructions = dict( 'what the steps are' )
for line in testdata_dicts:
    for i in range(1,MAX_STEPS):
        step = "step%s" % i 
        if instructions[step] == 'DOWNLOAD':
            download()
        elif instructions[step] == 'UPLOAD':
            upload()
        ...
```

Comment: it gives me an error `data = line[step]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: that's just pesudocode.

line should be a dict , like what your script above returns.  i updated it to read testdata_dicts

Comment: What I want to do essentially from the text file is vased on the steps process each line of each step, so for example, if step1 = WebAddress I want to go to the URL, then if step2 = Tab, i want to navigate to that tab and so on, but when I finish step8, i want it to restart with the next line.

Comment: Any ideas? To assign steps to the loops.

Comment: No that doesn't work, is there anyway I can read the first step and then continue until done, and then restart?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how your code breaks -- that would have helped.

I tried to see what your code does, and observe that the way columns are read is off by 3 positions. That's due to the three `\\` in each line. But I don't know if the input text you provided is accurate and you indeed end up with this text. Let me know.

```
...
header_names = [s.replace("_"," ").strip() for s in headers]
for line in post_data_lines[1:]:
    columns  = []
    column_start = 0
    print 'line %r.' % line
    for header in headers:
        column = line[column_start:column_start+len(header)]
        print 'read column %r.' % column
        print 'used header %r.' % header
        columns.append('%s' % column)
        column_start += len(header) + 1
    break
```

This outputs:

```
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\%s\raw\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Interim MBS: Single-Family                                      Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
read column 'https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/ '.
used header 'WebAddress___________________________'.
read column 'q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Ad'.
used header 'Destination___________'.
read column 'anced Search  In'.
used header 'Tab_____________'.
read column 'erim MBS: Single-Family                                      Is'.
used header 'SecurityType___________________________________________________'.
read column 'ue Date  09'.
used header 'Criteria___'.
read column '01/2012  Se'.
used header 'Date_______'.
read column 'rch  10'.
used header 'Click1_'.
read column '      CS'.
used header 'Results_'.
read column ' XML'.
used header 'Download'.
```

You'll see that starting from the second column, it's 3 chars off.

The way to fix this is by shortening the Destination header written in you file by three underscores:

```
Destination___________
Destination________
```